# Unable to print directory

Tags: java, directory

My code won't compile. I think it has to do with directory path, because I keep getting error message. I am trying to print out my sample directory( SampleDir) located in Desktop. Can someone help me with the directory path? Thank you in advance!

```
public class WalkDirectory {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       File [] files = new File("C:/SampleDir").listFiles(); 
       showFiles(files);            
    }   
    private static void showFiles(File[] files) {

        for(File file: files) {
            if(file.isDirectory()) { 
                System.out.println("Directory: " + file.getName());
                showFiles(file.listFiles()); // files from the existing directory or current directory
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("File: " + file.getName());

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: If it won't compile, provide the error. If it will compile, provide the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Your `}` characters are misplaced.
The code wad edited and in the edited code, it misses a `}` character at the end.
 For info, in the original, one was misplaced and another was missing (the last) I believe.

Try that :

```
import java.io.File;

public class WalkDirectory {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
      File[] files = new File("C:/SampleDir").listFiles();    
      showFiles(files);
    }

    private static void showFiles(File[] files) {

      for (File file : files) {
          if (file.isDirectory()) {
          System.out.println("Directory: " + file.getName());
          showFiles(file.listFiles()); // files from the existing directory or current directory
          }
          else {
               System.out.println("File: " + file.getName());    
          }
      }

    }
}
```

**EDIT**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   WalkDirectory.showFiles(WalkDirectory.java:16) at
>   WalkDirectory.main(WalkDirectory.java:11)

I suppose that the NPE is triggered in the foreach

```
 for (File file : files)
```

because files array is `nulL`.

You should write that to check that the folder exists :

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final File dirWithFiles = new File("C:/SampleDir");

    //check folder exist and is a directory
    if (!dirWithFiles.exist()) {
        System.out.println("dir " + dirWithFiles + " does not exit");
        return;
    }
    if (!dirWithFiles.isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("dir " + dirWithFiles + " is not a directory");
        return;
    }
    // end check
    File[] files = dirWithFiles.listFiles();
    showFiles(files);
   }
```

If the folder control fails, you should check in your filesystem that the input folder used in the application exists.

Comment: Thank you davidxxx, but it's not the missing brace. I didn't paste the code correctly on here. I think it has do with the file pathname, since that is where I keep getting error message. Appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome :) But in this case, I don't think that it is a compilation problem but a runtime exception. Can you post the stacktrace with all information ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at WalkDirectory.showFiles(WalkDirectory.java:16)
 at WalkDirectory.main(WalkDirectory.java:11)

Comment: above are the list of my exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Windows env, I think the problem is in how you declare the path: "C:/SampleDir"..
Try with something like that:

```
String path = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Your User\\Desktop\\SampleDir";
File[] files = new File(path).listFiles();
```

Comment: I have tried it, and it doesn't work. I just want to print the sample directory(SampleDir) that I have created, located on my Desktop. What would be the right way to write the pathway to my directory(SampleDir)? Thank you!

Comment: I tested your code on ubuntu with this path "/home/myname/desktop/mydir" and it works. You can find the exact file path of your SampleDir in this way: right click on SampleDir folder --> properties --> file path. Are you on a windows or unix OS?

Comment: I am using mac OS. How do I find the exact file path?

Comment: right click on SampleDir folder --> Get Info you should see something like that: http://i.i.cbsi.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim/2013/04/05/InfoWindowFilePath.png

Comment: Thank you for your patience!  path = "C:/iCloudDrive/Desktop/SampleDir";

Comment: String path = "C:/iCloudDrive/Desktop/SampleDir";
     File[] files = new File(path).listFiles();

Comment: try without "C:". String path = "/iCloudDrive/Desktop/SampleDir"; but it's really weird..

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {    
     String path = "C:/iCloudDrive/Desktop/SampleDir";
     File[] files = new File(path).listFiles();
     
     
    
    }

    private static void showFiles(File[] files) {

      for (File file : files) {
          if (file.isDirectory()) {
          System.out.println("Directory: " + file.getName());
          showFiles(file.listFiles()); // files from the existing directory or current directory
          }
          else {
               System.out.println("File: " + file.getName());    
          }

Comment: Thank you for trying. It's not working. I appreciate your help.